# Windows 8.1, moving OneDrive folder mistakenly set to user folder

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

In the process of migrating a data drive to a new SSD drive, I changed the OneDrive folder for Windows 8.1 to my user folder (e.g., "c:\users\ {username}"), thinking that it would create a new OneDrive folder in the user folder, so that I could later move the OneDrive folder to the new drive.  Instead, my user folder now displays as OneDrive, and further attempts to move OneDrive to a different folder generate an error "Can't move the folder because there is a folder in the same location that can't be redirected.  Access is denied."  I've disabled OneDrive syncing, and even attempted to change the folder name in the registry, yet OneDrive will not change.  This has not led to any problems with the user folder or account, as the user folder is still apparently accessible via the original folder name.  I had even thought of copying the user folder to a new folder and renaming to the original user folder, but when a folder is set to be the OneDrive folder, the rename option is not available.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a new user profile, then move files to the new user's directory by taking ownership of the old profile.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but may help others:

Source: [Operation to change a personal folder location fails in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/2936105)

> **Important** 
>   Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, back up the registry for restoration in case problems occur.
>
> To work around this issue, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Right-click the Windows logo at the lower-left corner of the screen, and then click **Run**.
> 2. Type regedit.exe and press Enter. If **User Account Control** window pops up, click **Yes**.
> 3. In Registry Editor, browse to the following path:
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
> 4. Refer to the following table to find the registry key for the folder that encounters this issue, and change it to the default value.
>
>    ```
>    Folder      Registry key    Default value
>    Downloads   {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}  %USERPROFILE%\Downloads
>    Desktop     Desktop         %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
>    Favorites   Favorites       %USERPROFILE%\Favorites
>    Music       My Music        %USERPROFILE%\Music
>    Pictures    My Pictures     %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
>    Videos      My Video        %USERPROFILE%\Videos
>    Documents   Personal        %USERPROFILE%\Documents
>    ```
> 5. Restart the Explorer.exe process to make the changes take effect. To do this, you can use either of the following steps:
>
>    - Restart the process in Task Manager.
>    - Sign out, and then sign in.
>    - Restart the computer.

Answer (score -1):

just unlink ur pc from onedrive

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some instructions...